# stripeToken is not being returned to my form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, stripe-payments

I have my Stripe integration setup correctly, because it does return an error `This customer has no attached payment source` which is a Stripe error indicating that the form is not returning sufficient payment info.

This is my `subscriptions.js.coffee`:

```
stripeResponseHandler = (status, response) ->
  $form = $('#payment-form')
  if response.error
    #Show the errors on the form
    $form.find('.payment-errors').text response.error.message
    $form.find('button').prop 'disabled', false
  else
    # response contains id and card, which contains additional card details
    token = response.id
    #Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    $form.append $('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token)
    # and submit
    $form.get(0).submit()
  return

jQuery ($) ->
  $('payment-form').submit (event) ->
    $form = $(this)
    $form.find('button').attr 'disabled', true
    Stripe.card.createToken $form, stripeResponseHandler
    false
  return
```

This is my form at `new.html.erb`:

```
<% unless @subscription.errors.blank? %>
  <%= @subscription.errors.full_messages.to_sentence %>
<% end %>

<h2>Subcribing to <%= @plan.name %></h2>

<%= form_for @subscription, html: {id: 'payment-form'} do |f| %>
  <input type="hidden" name="plan_id", value="<%= @plan.id %>" />
  <span class="payment-errors"></span>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>Email Address</span>
      <input type="email" size="20" name="email_address" />
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>Card Number</span>
      <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number" />
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>CVC</span>
      <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc" />
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>Expiration (MM/YYYY)</span>
      <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp-month" />
    </label>
    <span> / </span>
    <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="exp-year" />
  </div>

  <button type="submit">Pay Now</button>
<% end %>
```

This is the `SubscriptionsController#Create`:

```
  def create
    @plan = Plan.find(params[:plan_id])
    @subscription = CreateSubscription.call(
      @plan,
      params[:email_address],
      params[:stripeToken]
    )
    if @subscription.errors.blank?
      flash[:notice] = "Thank you for your purchase! Please click the link in the email we just sent you to get started."
      redirect_to authenticated_root_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

The above calls this `app/services/create_subscription.rb`:

```
class CreateSubscription
  def self.call(plan, email_address, token)
    user, raw_token = CreateUser.call(email_address)

    subscription = Subscription.new(
      plan: plan,
      user: user
    )

    begin
      stripe_sub = nil
      if user.stripe_customer_id.blank?
        binding.pry
        customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
          source: token,
          email: user.email,
          plan: plan.stripe_id
        )

        user.stripe_customer_id = customer.id
        user.save!
        stripe_sub = customer.subscriptions.first
      else
        customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(user.stripe_customer_id)
        stripe_sub = customer.subscriptions.create(
          plan: plan.stripe_id
        )
      end

      subscription.stripe_id = stripe_sub.id

      subscription.save!
    rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
      subscription.errors[:base] << e.message
    end

    subscription
  end
end
```

The reason I know that the form is not receiving the `stripeToken` is because when I use `binding.pry` in that `create` and did this:

```
00:52:31 web.1              |     14: def create
00:52:31 web.1              |     15:   @plan = Plan.find(params[:plan_id])
00:52:31 web.1              |  => 16:   binding.pry
00:52:31 web.1              |     17:   @subscription = CreateSubscription.call(
00:52:31 web.1              |     18:     @plan,
00:52:31 web.1              |     19:     params[:email_address],
00:52:31 web.1              |     20:     params[:stripeToken]
00:52:31 web.1              |     21:   )
00:52:31 web.1              |     22:   if @subscription.errors.blank?
00:52:31 web.1              |     23:     flash[:notice] = "Thank you for your purchase! Please click the link in the email we just sent you to get started."
00:52:31 web.1              |     24:     redirect_to authenticated_root_path
00:52:31 web.1              |     25:   else
00:52:31 web.1              |     26:     render :new
00:52:31 web.1              |     27:   end
00:52:31 web.1              |     28: end
00:52:31 web.1              | 
[1] pry(#<SubscriptionsController>)> params
00:52:37 web.1              | => {"utf8"=>"✓", "plan_id"=>"1", "email_address"=>"someuser@test.com", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"subscriptions"}
```

Notice that there is no `params[:stripeToken]`.

Also, when I try the `binding.pry` in my `create_subscription.rb` service, this is what I get:

```
00:52:41 web.1              |     10:     begin
00:52:41 web.1              |     11:       stripe_sub = nil
00:52:41 web.1              |     12:       if user.stripe_customer_id.blank?
00:52:41 web.1              |  => 13:         binding.pry
00:52:41 web.1              |     14:         customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
00:52:41 web.1              |     15:           source: token,
00:52:41 web.1              |     16:           email: user.email,
00:52:41 web.1              |     17:           plan: plan.stripe_id
00:52:41 web.1              |     18:         )
00:52:41 web.1              | 
[1] pry(CreateSubscription)> token
00:52:44 web.1              | => nil
```

What could be causing this and how do I fix it?

Comment: Maybe that param needs to be part of the whitelist for that controller? Seems like it might be a strong params issue.

Comment: @Armando - I don't specify other params in the controller. The others just work. Would I still need to specify this one only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, my issue was a dumb mistake.

Notice in my CoffeeScript I have this:

```
jQuery ($) ->
  $('payment-form').submit (event) ->
    $form = $(this)
    $form.find('button').attr 'disabled', true
    Stripe.card.createToken $form, stripeResponseHandler
    false
  return
```

The issue is in the form selector. I didn't add the `#` to the ID of the form.

So once I changed this line:

```
  $('payment-form').submit (event) ->
```

To this:

```
  $('#payment-form').submit (event) ->
```

It works like a charm.

DOH! *Faceslap*